# how to set method become array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class file name serializedObject, I will like to call this class file in another class file and use it's method.

I want to declare the class file became and array to being use in another class file.
Then I declare something like below:

```
serializedObject[] setData = new serializedObject[10];
```

and use it into a for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<clientInfo.length; i++)
{

double locationX = clientInfo[i].getLocation().getX();
double locationY = clientInfo[i].getLocation().getY();
String name = clientInfo[i].getName();
double mood = clientInfo[i].getMood();
double hunger = clientInfo[i].getHunger();
double chargestate = clientInfo[i].getChargestate();

setData[i].setAll(locationX, locationY, name, mood, hunger, chargestate);
System.out.println(setData[i].getName());

}
```

In the serializedObject class I have the set method and also get method,
but seems like not work for this. What can i do instead of this way to get an array method?
Thanks for any comment and help.

The system seems like cant really set my value into the method,
i cant get the any value from the

```
System.out.println(setData[i].getName());
```

but the system doesn't have any compile error.

Here will be my serializedObject class file

```
public class serializedObject
{
    public static double locationX;
    public static double locationY;
    public static String name;
    public static double mood;
    public static double hunger;
    public static double chargestate;

    public serializedObject()
    {
    }


    public void setAll(double locationX,double locationY, String name,double mood,double hunger, double chargestate)
    {

        this.locationX = locationX;
        this.locationY = locationY;
        this.name = name;
        this.mood = mood;
        this.hunger = hunger;
        this.chargestate = chargestate;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;   
    }

    public double getLocationX()
    {
        return this.locationX;  
    }

    public double getLocationY()
    {
        return this.locationY;  
    }

    public double getMood()
    {
        return this.mood;   
    }

    public double getHunger()
    {
        return this.hunger; 
    }

    public double getChargestate()
    {
        return this.chargestate;    
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried for the set/get methods?  Why didn't they work for you? It would help if you showed the methods you were having trouble with.

Comment: What does "not work" precisely mean? Do you get a compilation error, a runtime exception, an unexpected result, or ...?

Comment: The setAll function cant really set the thing in, when i try to get back the value, i din't get anything of it. Just like ignore from the system and there is no any compile error.

Comment: @vincent: You need to give us a complete example (the minimum amount of code that clearly demonstrates the problem).   Obviously we can't tell you why your `setAll` method isn't working if you don't *show* us your `setAll` method.

Comment: @Mark Peters thanks for comment, i had updated the code over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this `serializedObject[] setData = new serializedObject[10];` will just create the array. All elements are still null thus calling methods on those elements (like `getName()`) will result in a NullPointerException. You'd have to initialize the elements first: `setData [0] = new serializedObject();` then you call call methods on the element.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *by convention*, the initial letter of a class name should be capitalized as such, `SerializedObject`. In your for-loop, you'll need to do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < clientInfo.length; i++)
{
    // Construct new serialized object
    setData[i] = new SerializedObject();

    // Extract client information
    double locationX = clientInfo[i].getLocation().getX();
    double locationY = clientInfo[i].getLocation().getY();
    String name = clientInfo[i].getName();
    double mood = clientInfo[i].getMood();
    double hunger = clientInfo[i].getHunger();
    double chargestate = clientInfo[i].getChargestate();

    // Store information in serialized object
    setData[i].setAll(locationX, locationY, name, mood, hunger, chargestate);

    // Add serialized object to array
    System.out.println(setData[i].getName());

}
```

**Note:** At the moment, your program should be throwing a *NullPointerException*, which should have let you know that the elements within `setData` are `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double locationX;
public static double locationY;
public static String name;
public static double mood;
public static double hunger;
public static double chargestate;
```

These properties are all *static*.  That means they will be shared between **all instances** of serializedObject.  Therefore, if you do `setAll` on one instance, it will seem to change every other instance.

You should make these instance members:

```
public double locationX;
public double locationY;
public String name;
public double mood;
public double hunger;
public double chargestate;
```

Fields should usually not be public, but that's a separate discussion.